# Is it allowed to visit a man's house when he isn't home for repair work?

Tags: fiqh, women, work, men-women

Assalau Alaikum to my Muslim Brothers,

If a Muslim client who is a male is out of town and his wife is Alone at home, is it permissible for 2 male contractors at the permission of the husband to visit the house to carry out a few measurements and repairs?

I know that a single male contractor visiting the house of the client where his wife will be alone, is absolutely haram. But my question is, what if 2 or 3 men go along for the job?

Please give me some references

Comment: In case of a 2:1 situation 2 women versus 1 men are preferred not the opposite. Scholars say a woman would be more shameful in front of another woman than men would be, this can be witnessed in daily life.

Comment: Also a woman may leave a stranger enter her house with the permission of her husband, under certain conditions.